# Hot water heater flush valves too close

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have an outdoor Rheem water heater that I want to flush/descale (run vinegar through it).

Problem is, the two flush valves (hot and cold) are so close to each other that I can’t fit my hose to connect it to them.

Is there any kind of solution that can get me around this and able to connect hoses?

I’m attaching a couple of pictures here to show this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have made tight installations before but leaving access is key. Was the fitter blessed with an IQ in single digits?

I would rotate the right hand one (blue) by 90 degrees then it can still be turned off etc as well as both unions used.

Comment: Ha, yes tell me about it. How do I rotate it exactly?

Comment: How you rotate it depends on what's beneath that foam insulation.  Cut off about two inches and post another picture of that.  Cut a 2 inch slit down the length of it then cut around the pipe at the bottom of the slit.  Cut carefully in case it's plastic pipe underneath.

Comment: @jay613 well, delete and replace - your comment is a lot shorter now...

Comment: @solarmike my original comment
 was up for about 20 seconds. Well spotted!   Hopefully that offended nobody, my original understanding was access to any means of draining (suggested prv) then realized access required to both ports at once for circulating descaler.